# Image processing for web app: on server or in browser?

Tags: web-applications, image-processing

I am looking into making a web app out of a program I wrote that evolves images and uses PIL (Python Imaging Library) for image processing. I am new to web development, however, and am not sure whether I should put the fairly computationally expensive image processing component of my application on the web server using something like Java Servlets or (for python) WSGI, or in the browser using Javascript on the HTML5 canvas. I made a bare bones web.py app that does the image processing on the server, but my initial tests show significant latency in sending the synthesized images over HTTP to the client (they are small, 200x200 pixel images). What is your advice? How would you approach this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can process an image on both server side and browser side.  Generate your images on the server with a Java Servlet using say java.awt.Image and manipulate/annotate the presentation of images in the browser using HTML5 Canvas.  Latency will most likely be caused by processing the image on the server not the transmission to a browser.  Because of the time taken to process an image on the server you may need to process the image asynchronously and deliver it in ajax style to avoid locking out the user's browser.  You can detect if users browser has HTML5 support using Modernizr from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

if you plan on having a high availability site, using the clients processing and memory power makes sense, but HTML5 isn't fully supported by the majority of browsers being used just yet. you are probably better off using server side editing at the moment. you will want to process the images on upload if possible and store the edited image so that you only have to process them each one time. not sure if this is possible in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to implement some Cloud Processing solution server side. In this way it will be scalable with the number of users. You don't mention the type of image processing that is done but for some complicated algorithms this can become very intensive.